# Finding length of nested json array in Java

Tags: java

I have a junk of json that has a nested json array inside of it.  What would be the best way to get that nested json out and then get the length of it. I want to get the two fields inside of "/details"  then use them

```
{
  "Lane2":[
    {
      "authHost":"host.com",
      "action-items":[
        {
          "/details":[
            {
              "path":"/something/details",
              "httpMethod":"get"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "/summary":[
            {
              "path":"/something/summary",
              "httpMethod":"get"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "/summary":[
            {
              "path":"/action-items/summary",
              "httpMethod":"get"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Um, use a Json parser?

Comment: http://www.json.org/java/ Have fun.

Comment: I have tried using a parser and when I pull action-items into its own array the length should be 3 right?  I am only getting one

Comment: Then show us some code.   *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Answer (score 0):

I agree use the JSON parser, here's a simple example if you want to try on your own:

```
public String[] parseJA(JSONArray input, String[] key) throws JSONException{ 
        // Parses a JSONArray with matching KEY value into a Sring[]
        output = new String[input.length()];
        joOutput = new JSONObject[input.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length();++i) {
            output[i] = input.getString(i);
            joOutput[i] = input.getJSONObject(i);
            output[i] = joOutput[i].getString(key[i]);      
        }
        return output;  
    }
```